# How to add svg on top of another svg in d3,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.js to build a stacked bar graph. I am referring to this graph http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

I want to add a small square of different color on the bars which have equal value. For example in this graph- if population of ***25 to 44 Years*** and ***45 to 64 Years*** is equal then i want to show a square of 10,10(width,height) on both bars related to CA. This is what I was doing but its not showing on the bar:

```
var equalBar = svg.selectAll(".equalBar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "equalBar")
            .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + x(d.states) + ",0"; }); 

equalBar.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d.ages;} )
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("width", 10)
.attr("y", function(d){
    return y(d.y1);
})
.attr("height", function(d)
      { return 10; })
.style("fill", "green");
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't really compatible with the D3 approach to data management. The idea of selections relies on the data items to be independent, whereas in your case you want to compare them explicitly.

The approach I would take to do this is to create a new data structure that contains the result of these comparisons. That is, for each population group it tells you what other groups it is equal to. You can then use this new data to create the appropriate rectangles.

Comment: Is there any other way by which we can put asterisk mark on equal bars or on side of those bars. Because I tried to implement this using bootstrap's icons but it require an html element to be present at the place where we want it to show. But this solution is not working for me.

Comment: Regardless of what you're using as a marker, you'll have to compute the position of the marker yourself.